# SimpleViewer + lightbox

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to integrate any kind of Lightbox with SimpleViewer? But I **don't want** to display SimpleViewer in Lightbox. I want to Lightbox show when I click on one of the images in SimpleViewer.

Does anyone tried that with success?

**EDIT**
I have a SimpleViewer page now. I just want to bind handler to clicking an image (as normally in HTML based pages), fetch big image url and show that image (not SimpleViewer!) in Ligthbox/ThickBox/FancyBox etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), which uses jQuery, can do this.

Comment: I couldn't find it in documentation. They write about embeding flash in ThickBox and showing Thickbox over flash using `wmode`. Could you point me an resource, where somebody done what I'm asking, it means - I click on SimpleViewer image (flash) and ThickBox/LightBox with that clicked image shows.

Comment: Thickbox lets you open a URL up in an iframe. So all you need to do is place SimpleViewer in it's own page and then call it will Thickbox. The page containing SimpleViwer will be very basic as all it will contain is the SimpleViewer and I'm sure it can be dynamic if necessary.

Comment: I'm afraid that we do not understand each other. You're are saying about opening simple SimpleViewer in ThickBox window. But I have a SimpleViewer page now. I just want to bind handler to clicking an image (as normally in HTML based pages), fetch big image url and show that image, not SimpleViewer in ThickBox.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it that way. This way seems to be the closest you can get to that I can find.